# get a domain address with asp

Tags: asp-classic, dns

how do I get the domain of an address to the asp?

Suppose we have the following addresses:

example.com
example.com/my
example.com/news/nacional
example.com/news/naciona/nada-como-um-dia.html

I'd like to get just the domain, in this case o. ..

"example.com"

I take the field as an address to the asp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
Request.servervariables("SERVER_NAME")

Torbjørn